# Como unir dos subplots con un solo eje x en Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

Hola estoy usando Python (Matplotlib) y quisiera saber si existe documentación o algún código para obtener dos subplots en una sola columna y con un solo eje  x, como se muestra en la imagen:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`plt.subplots()` con `sharex=True` tendra el mismo eye para los dos plots. Solo el eje de abajo tendrá números. Con `gridspec_kw={'hspace': ...}` se puede arreglar la distancia entre los plots. Una distancia de `0` los pone totalmente pegado.  Una distancia de `1` sería la altura media de los plots. `tick_params(axis='x', direction='in')` pone los *ticks* hacia dentro.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data = np.random.randn(100, 350).cumsum(axis=0).cumsum(axis=1).cumsum(axis=0)
data -= data.min()
data *= 100 / data.max()
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(nrows=2, sharex=True, gridspec_kw={'hspace': 0.05})

ax1.plot(data.mean(axis=0))
ax1.tick_params(axis='x', direction='in')
ax2.imshow(data, cmap='inferno', origin='lower', aspect='auto')

plt.show()
```

[image: ejemplo]